# Spring Config file

Tags: spring

I am using Spring 3.1.0 version. But I am getting error while deployment due to dispatcher-servlet.xml. Here is the code I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.cart" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Error is :

```
 Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 5 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 93; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.. Please see server.log for more details.
```

I tried to find the correct bean file but not succeeded. Can you guys please advise where should i search the config file as per my spring version.

Comment: Error is:  Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 5 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 93; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.. Please see server.log for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you are missing namespace `context` and your schema location declarations are wrong

try

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.cart" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```